# microsoft visual studio minesweeper code

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, loops, minesweeper

Here is the code I have.  I am trying to add an onclick to each square so that when you click on that square you change it from a gray square to a square with its value. I have an 8 x 8 table. Also when I reveal a square I need to change its status so its no longer closed and shows its value.  Also I need to randomly place 8 mines into the minefield without placing two mines in the same spot. I can not figure out the code for this.

Please help!

Thanks!

```
    var aiSquareValue = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
    var aiSquareStatus = [["c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c"], ["o", "o", "o", "o", "o", "o", "o", "o"], ["f", "f", "f", "f", "f", "f", "f", "f", "f"]]
    var aiGridValue = 0
    var  bIsMatch = false


    function vBuild()
    {
        var strHTML
        var i, j


        //Start building the table
        strHTML = "<table style='margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto'>"

            strHTML += "<tr>"
            strHTML += "<td colspan='6' style='text-align:center; font-size:xx-large''>Minesweeper</td>"
                strHTML += "</tr>"
                strHTML += "<tr>"
                strHTML += "<td colspan='6' style='text-align:center' >"
                strHTML += "<input type='button' id='btnNewGame' value='New Game' onclick='vNewGame()'/>"
                strHTML += "</td>"
                strHTML += "</tr>"


        //Loop through the rows in the table
        for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            strHTML += "<tr>"
            //loops through the columns
            for (j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
                strHTML += "<td>"

                //add image tag
                strHTML += "<img src='GraySquare.png' id = 'img" + i + "," + j + "' onclick='vClick(" + i + "," + j + ")' />"

                strHTML += "</td>"
            }
            strHTML += "</tr>"              

        }

        strHTML += "<tr>"
        strHTML += "<td colspan='6' style='text-align:center' >"
        strHTML += "<textarea id='taOut' style='margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; text-align:center; align-content:center' rows='30' cols='60' ></textarea>"
        strHTML += "</td>"
        strHTML += "</tr>"
        strHTML += "</table>"

        //insert function in to document
        frmGrid.innerHTML = strHTML
    }

    function vMines()
    {
        var i, j;
        var iRow = (Math.floor(Math.random()*8))
        var iCol = (Math.floor(Math.random()*8))


        while (i <= 7) {
            aiSquareValue[iRow][iCol] = 9





        }


    }


    function vNewGame()
    {



    }

    function vClick()
    {




    }
```

Comment: A strategy could be having a single array with the indexes to the possible values; shuffling the array and picking the first `x` items. Fill the items with those indexes with mines.

Comment: So I have to change my code completely around? And how would I calculate the value of all the squares in the minefield after I have placed the mines?

Comment: Not necessarily; you could create an extra array within a loop that has something like `newArr[n]={x:0, y:4, hasMine:false}`. I don't understand the second question.

Comment: I am sorry I new to doing and am not familiar with that language of code you are using I guess. And my second question is, I am using (Math.floor(Math.Random(*8))) to get my random mines. (I am using the number 9 to represent the mines).  I cant figure out how to code it so it doesn't place the random 9 in the same array box twice and I only end up with 7 mines instead of the 8 I need.

Comment: To keep it simple and close to what you are having, you could try to check the value with `aiSquareValue[iRow][iCol] == 9` first, and  recalculate a random value when it is already set (or don't update `i` in that case, and let the while do an extra iteration).